# Knitting an HTML file wont publish the inference command

Tags: r, knitr, inference

I am currently doing a R course and I struggle with knitting an HTML file. 
All the code works fine within RStudio. The file also knits properly, however it wont plot an output for the last command, when I run the inference. I added the code.

Any input is much appreciated.
Thanks
Markus

---

Firstly, we filter for the religions and the year of interest:

```{r filter}

```
gss2012 = gss %>%
  filter(year =="2012")
gssCatPro2012 = gss2012 %>%
  filter(relig=="Catholic" | relig=="Protestant")
```

```

Now we create a first histogram of both religions to get a first idea of the distributions:

`{r plot both rel}
    ggplot(data=gssCatPro2012, aes(x=childs))+geom_histogram()`

Calculate ratio and represent in pie chart:

`{r ratio}
    gssCatPro2012 %>%
    summarise(Catholicratio = sum(relig =="Catholic")/n())
    percent <- c(32.64,67.36)
    lbls <- c("Catholics", "Protestants")
    pct <- round(percent/sum(percent)*100)
    lbls <- paste(lbls, pct)
    lbls <- paste(lbls,"%", sep="")
    pie(percent, labels=lbls, col=rainbow(length(lbls)), main="Pie chart         Catholics/Protestants")`

Split data between religions:

`{r split}
    gssCat2012 = gssCatPro2012 %>%
    filter(relig=="Catholic")
    gssPro2012 = gssCatPro2012 %>% 
    filter(relig=="Protestant")`

Plot first distribution of Catholics, then Protestants:

`{r plot per religion}
    ggplot(data=gssCat2012, aes(x=childs))+geom_histogram()
    ggplot(data=gssPro2012, aes(x=childs))+geom_histogram()`

Check if any NAs to clean:

`{r NA}
    anyNA(gssCatPro2012$childs)
    completeFun <- function(data, desiredCols) {
    completeVec <- complete.cases(data[, desiredCols])
    return(data[completeVec, ])
}
    gssCatPro2012=completeFun(gssCatPro2012,"childs")
    anyNA(gssCatPro2012$childs)`

Calculate means for both religions:

`{r metrics}
    gssCatPro2012 %>%
    group_by(relig) %>%
      summarise(mean_kids=mean(childs), med_kids=median(childs),     sd_kids=sd(childs),n=n())`

---

### Inference

We are going to create a new variable in order to overwrite the content of the old variable relig:
`{create new variable}
    gssCatPro2012new <- gssCatPro2012 %>%
      mutate(relignew = ifelse(relig == "Catholic", "Catholic", "Protestant"))`

Now, we can run the inference function and see whether we can reject the 0 Hypothesis or not:
`{hypothesis test}
    inference(y = childs, x = relignew, data = gssCatPro2012new, statistic = "mean", type = "ht", null = 0, alternative = "twosided", method = "theoretical")`

Comment: Are you missing the leading `r` in the opening lines for the last couple chunks? Also, I think the chunk name may not allow spaces. E.g. try "{r create_new_variable}" instead of "{create new variable}".

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith, I added the "r" and it worked. Pretty embarrassing really... Cheers, Markus

Comment: No problem - glad you got it sorted out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the chunk names to use underscores instead of spaces and make sure each chunk begins with a leading "r".

For example:

```
{r create_new_variable}
```

instead of:

```
{create new variable}
```